# I have a problem with passing variables to different components in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I want to send user information from Employees.jsx to Tasks.jsx Why when I use console.log(currentUser) in Tasks it is undefined? I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or not, but if I use console.log(user) to check the in useEffect in App.jsx it is undefined but when i use console.log(user) outside useEffect it is have a value and i check by use console.log(currentUser) in Tasks.jsx it is undefined.

```
App.jsx
function App() {
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);
  const [user, setcurrectUser] = useState({});
  const currentUser = (receiveUser) => {
    // console.log("currentUser");
    // console.log(receiveUser);
    setcurrectUser(receiveUser);
  }
  // console.log(user);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/getemployees").then((response) => {
      // console.log(response.data.employees);
      setEmployees(response.data.employees);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Employees getEmp={employees} sendUser={currentUser} />} />
        <Route path="/create" element={<InsertEmp />} />
        <Route path="/update/:id" element={<UpdateEmp />} />
        <Route path="/tasks" element={<Tasks currentUser={user} />} />
        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile currentUser={test} />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

```
Employees.jsx
function Employees(props) {
  const { getEmp, sendUser } = props;
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const headers = {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    };
    Axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3001/api/verify",
      {},
      { headers: headers }
    ).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.status === "ok") {
        console.log("success");
      } else {
        console.log("fail");
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
        window.location = "/";
      }
    });

    const temp = localStorage.getItem("user");
    const userTemp = JSON.parse(temp);
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/users/${userTemp.email}`).then(
      (response) => {
        // console.log(response.data.result[0]);
        setUser(response.data.result[0]);
        sendUser(response.data.result[0]);
      }
    );

  }, []);
```

```
Tasks.jsx
function Tasks(props) {
  const { currentUser } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentUser);
  }, []);
```

Comment: `currentUser` is a function, it can't be `undefined`.

Comment: i send props user to Tasks user it not function?, Where should i adjust? Thank you